# Ошибка Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Всем привет!

```
function info_page($DB) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM links 
              INNER JOIN info_page ON 
              links.parent_info = info_page.info_id 
              ORDER BY info_position, links_position";
    $res = mysqli_query($DB, $query) or die(mysqli_query());
    $info_pages = array();
    $name = ''; // флаг имени информера
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        if($row['info_name'] != $name) { // если такого информера в массиве еще нет
            $info_pages[$row['info_id']][] = $row['info_name']; // добавляем информер в массив
            $name = $row['info_name'];
        }
        $info_pages[$row['parent_info']]['sub'][$row['link_id']] = $row['link_name']; // заносим страницы в информер
    }
    return $info_pages;
}
//получение массива инфо
$info_pages = info_page($DB);
```

Выдает ошибку "mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 0 given"
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сделать

Comment: die(mysqli_query()); - что это за шаманство?

Comment: в php новичок, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: там должно быть что-то вроде or die(mysql_error()); хотя лучше в таком стиле вообще не писать, а юзать хотя бы pdo и ловить исключения, а не убивать скрипты в месте ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Это ошибка именно изза этого кусочка кода

> $res = mysqli_query($DB, $query) or die(mysqli_query());

Поменяйте на

> $res = mysqli_query($DB, $query) or die();

И вообще используйте лучше PDO: http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.connections.php